# Tracking Application Usage in iOS and logging to file

Tags: iphone, ios

I am developing an SDK for iOS. It basically help developers to use our service by placing button in any one of the screen. More than that, we are providing analytics. 
In a website, I can provide a javascript snippet, which will help us track the usage and log it for analytics. Developers can place it in any template which is used universally (like in footer.html) and forget about it. 
What would the ideal approach for the same in iOS. Basically I would like developers to init our service from AppDelegate or any one point and it should track the usage. Data that I would like to track are

1. User's id,app version, app id, etc. (Can be collected at the point the library is inited)
2. Usage time (time from the app was opened to went to background, which again can be tracked easily)
3. Viewcontrollers loaded and from where it was loaded (Couldn't find a solution unless developer extend viewcontroller from our class, or we write a category. Need a better solution as in AOP)
4. Button clicks (Same as 3rd point)

For all these, if we provide a solution like call [OurLibrary passFlag:VIEWCONTROLLERLOADED withViewController:self] will help it. But we don't want developers to do it explicitly.

Idea is to have our integration as easy as possible for the developers. Any ideas folks?

Comment: Just look how TestFlight do it and imitate them.  (see `TestFlight.h`).

Comment: In testflight, to perform #3 and #4 in my requirement, I have to use their checkpoint API which is something like "[TestFlight passCheckpoint:@"CHECKPOINT_NAME"];"  That is similar to what I have said in last paragraph of my query. I don't prefer the developers doing it explicitly. They can init our library at any one point of the application and rest of the data collection should be automatic without developer having to add more code.